# Fetch API when should I explicitly set the `Content-Type` header?

Tags: javascript, http, fetch, content-type

What is the best practice when it comes to setting the `Content-Type` header on `fetch` requests?

I spent several hours today tracking down a bug because I was doing what I thought was a good practice: setting the `Content-Type` header of my requests according to the type of the content I was sending.

Specifically, I was sending a POST request with `Content-Type` of `multipart/form-data` (for file uploading). What I didn't know is the browser will automatically set the `Content-Type` header of `multipart/form-data` requests, **and** it will append a required `boundary` value to the `Content-Type` header.

I've run into issues in the past trying to POST JSON data *without* setting the `Content-Type` header, and now I'm running into issues trying to POST files *while* setting the `Content-Type` header.

Is there a good rule of thumb here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Post method first, we have to specify type of the content we are sending
like JSON or text/plain or images if we are posting files we are using 
new FormData() constructor to set key value pairs

**The FormData interface provides a way to easily construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values, which can then be easily sent using the XMLHttpRequest.send() method. It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data".** check on  [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

***check this on mdn clearly tells why headers are not used in [Content-headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)***

Comment: @SimpleJ not really understanding why this is a sufficient answer